# What would be a derisive term for a scooter (moped)?

Tags: single-word-requests

A boat or ship can be a tub or a frying pan.
A car is a jalopy.

A scooter would be? ...

[image]

Comment: one bad motorscooter

Comment: @HippoSawrUs Very funny.

Comment: *putt-putt* was the only other term I could think of…

Comment: One that's small and underpowered like a toy, or one that's old and beat-up but would have been good when it was new?

Comment: To build on Stuart F's question, what aspect in particular are you intending to deride?  Your picture is of a new, comfortable, and probably fairly responsive motor scooter that would provide convenient transportation in a city with narrow streets. Are you astride a Harley Davidson "hog" and dismissing it as a "toy", and saying it's ill-suited to the open highway? Or saying that it's poorly made and won't last very long under frequent use?

Comment: …besides *pocket rocket* and that's just condescending and vulgar at the same time. I'd call a scooter club.

Comment: I didn't realize **pocket rocket** was condescending and vulgar. How do you feel about "rocket docket"?

Comment: Who thinks I'm wrong to say 'jalopy' is only so slightly derogatory, it doesn't truly belong here?

Comment: @TimR I think it's vulgar because it's also slang for a type of dildo.

Comment: I call them *dollar beer nights*, because the parking lot at the local watering hole is full of them on dollar beer night.

Comment: A frying pan?? A Clorox bottle, maybe, but I've never hear of a frying pan boat.

Comment: @TimR - I didn't either; I always search the slang meanings first, but they're doing too much…all the words. *Rocket docket* will be the word of the year, and then it'll mean something else entirely.

Comment: @Barmar. LOL, It's also the name for a small backpacking stove.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a single word, but **hairdyer on wheels** has a handful of hits if you search for it.

https://www.google.com/search?q=moped+%22hairdryer+on+wheels%22

It's probably not common enough to be used without additional description, but tbh I wouldn't know what you were talking about if you said you were going out for a trip in your frying pan at the weekend either, so maybe they're both subculture-specific terms :-)...

Answer (score 1):

The site [Ridenow - powersports](https://www.ridenowchandler.com/blog/funny-motorcycle-terms-you-should-know--832) suggests:

***Rat Bike***

> A beat-up, crappy bike that looks like it's broken down.

Answer (score 1):

**Tiddler**.

> A somewhat derogatory term meaning “small bike” or “beginner bike.” Typically, street bikes under 250cc qualify as tiddlers. Usage: “My friend wanted to get a Gixxer for his first bike, but I don’t want him to die so I told him to learn on a tiddler.”

From [Get up to speed with our comprehensive dictionary of motorcycle slang](https://www.themanual.com/auto/motorcycle-slang-lingo-terms-terminology-dictionary/).

Comment: I believe **tiddler** must be UK. I wouldn't know what it meant, though it sounds close to **piddler**.

Comment: @TimR specifically a small fish, but [anything small](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tiddler). It's also in the link in the question.

Answer (score 1):

In Britain the derisive term **"pop-bike"** is sometimes used to make fun of motor bikes and scooters.

Originally a *pop-bike" is a child's bicycle. Here for example is a toddler's pop bike, complete with stabilising wheels. So to refer to an adult's motor bike or scooter in this way demeans all three: the machine, the owner, and their competence to ride the machine.

> [Halfords](https://www.cyclesuk.com/shop/bikes/sub/kids/raleigh-pop-14-white-61010/option/)
> *The Raleigh Pop 14" bike is for kids ...*
> [image]